# R Paired t.test Error in x - y : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r

when running the following code to extract some data from an excel sheet and plot/run a simple paired t.test.....

```
#install.packages("readxl")
#load readxl
library("readxl")
getwd()
#set working directory
setwd('/Volumes/DANIEL')

#read in xlsx files
diffusion_data = read_excel("diffusion_stats.xlsx", sheet = "ROI_MD")
#create data frame with diffusion data
diffusion_data = data.frame(diffusion_data)
#create column (turn condition into a factorial) and create summary for columns
condition=diffusion_data[,2]
condition=as.factor(condition)
SpleniumCC=as.numeric(diffusion_data[,3])
BodyCC=as.numeric(diffusion_data[,4])
GenuCC=as.numeric(diffusion_data[,5])
Fornix_Body=as.numeric(diffusion_data[,6])
R_Cing_Hipp=as.numeric(diffusion_data[,7])
L_Cing_Hipp=as.numeric(diffusion_data[,8])
R_Uncinate_Fasc=as.numeric(diffusion_data[,9])
L_Uncinate_Fasc=as.numeric(diffusion_data[,10])


summary(SpleniumCC)
summary(BodyCC)
summary(GenuCC)
summary(Fornix_Body)
summary(R_Cing_Hipp)
summary(L_Cing_Hipp)
summary(R_Uncinate_Fasc)
summary(L_Uncinate_Fasc)

#plot columns
hist(SpleniumCC, main='SpleniumCC')
hist(BodyCC, main='BodyCC')
hist(GenuCC, main='GenuCC')
hist(Fornix_Body, main='Fornix_Body')
hist(R_Cing_Hipp, main="R_Cing_Hipp")
hist(L_Cing_Hipp, main='L_Cing_Hipp')
hist(R_Uncinate_Fasc, main='R_Uncin')
hist(L_Uncinate_Fasc, main='L_Uncin')

plot(condition, SpleniumCC, main='SpleniumCC')
plot(condition, BodyCC, main='BodyCC')
plot(condition, GenuCC, main='GenuCC')
plot(condition, Fornix_Body, main='Fornix_Body')
plot(condition, R_Cing_Hipp, main="R_Cing_Hipp")
plot(condition, L_Cing_Hipp, main='L_Cing_Hipp')
plot(condition, R_Uncinate_Fasc, main='R_Uncin')
plot(condition, L_Uncinate_Fasc,left_hipp, main='L_Uncin')

#run paired ttest on columns
t.test(SpleniumCC~condition, mu=0, paired=T, data = diffusion_data)
t.test(BodyCC~condition, mu=0, paired=T, data = diffusion_data)
t.test(GenuCC~condition, mu=0, paired=T, data = diffusion_data)
t.test(Fornix_Body~condition, mu=0, paired=T, data = diffusion_data)
t.test(R_Cing_Hipp~condition, mu=0, paired=T, data = diffusion_data)
t.test(L_Cing_Hipp~condition, mu=0, paired=T, data = diffusion_data)
t.test(R_Uncinate_Fasc~condition, mu=0, paired=T, data = diffusion_data)
t.test(L_Uncinate_Fasc~condition, mu=0, paired=T, data = diffusion_data)
```

I get this error...
Error in x - y : non-numeric argument to binary operator

I ran this same code on a different excel sheet and it worked without issue. While the numbers in the two different sheets are different there should be no other differences in formatting. There are also no differences in the  R code other than the sheet = "ROI_FA" part.

Answer (score 0):

You need to identify parameter using a comma. Try

```
> t.test(SpleniumCC, condition, mu=0, paired=T, data = diffusion_data)
```

or more explicitly

```
> t.test(x=SpleniumCC, y=condition, mu=0, paired=T, data = diffusion_data)
```